# Tic-Tac-Toe Board not updating with player move

Tags: java, arrays, tic-tac-toe

So I am making a program that takes a row int and a col int from the keyboard in the main, and passes them into the constructor. This creates a String matrix using those values passed in and they are all set to the string "space", which is assigned to "___". Now my problem rises when I try to replace any element in the array with the player move "human" which is assigned to "*x*". Whenever I try to do this, say with row 1 and col 1, I get a null pointer exception and the program breaks. I am trying to do this on my own so I'm only going to try and put in as much code as I think is necessary but any help in replacing these elements would be fantastic.

```
 {
private int row;
private int col;
private String [][] board;
private String space = "___";
private String human = "_x_";
private String comp = "_o_";
private String output = "";
public Move()
{

}
public Move(int r, int c)
{
    row = r;
    col = c;
    board = new String [row][col];
}

public String [][] genMatrix()
{
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            board[i][j] = space;
        }
    }
    return board;
}

public String playermove()
{
    row = row - 1;
    col = col - 1;
    if(board[row][col].equals(space))
    {
        board[row][col] = human;
        return "";
    }
    else
    {
        return "That space has already been filled, try again.";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to call genMatrix in the constructor.

Some things are unclear:

1. Is is assumed to be 3*3 matrix or as per user discretion (say m*n)?
2. We initialize m*n in constructor, but genMatrix just takes care of 3*3.

Comment: genMatrix is being called in the main before any player moves take place. And I print an "example board" which is a 3 by 3 matrix, the user input is only the row and column that they would like to move into

Comment: I think a better question would be: how to I actually replace an element in a string matrix with another string. Because that seems to be the inherent problem, hence the null pointer error

Comment: Problem is not with replacement step - its in the if block decision


    if(board[row][col].equals(space)) // here is the problem, equals method is executed on the null.